# after form submission through contact form 7 I want to check weather the email exist in previous 6 months of time it should throw error

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using contact form 7 plugin for form submission and storing data by using contact-form-7-to-database-extension. by using below code it is checking whether the email exist previously or not but I want to check with only previous 6 months of data, not complete data

```
function is_already_submitted($formName, $fieldName, $fieldValue) {
  require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7-to-database-extension/CFDBFormIterator.php');
$exp = new CFDBFormIterator();
$atts = array();
$atts['show'] = $fieldName;
$atts['filter'] = "$fieldName=$fieldValue";
$atts['unbuffered'] = 'true';
$exp->export($formName, $atts);
$found = false;
while ($row = $exp->nextRow()) {
    $found = true;
}
return $found;
}

/**
* @param $result WPCF7_Validation
* @param $tag array
* @return WPCF7_Validation
*/
function my_validate_email($result, $tag) {
$formName = 'Career Form'; // Change to name of the form containing this field
$fieldName = 'email'; // Change to your form's unique field name
$errorMessage = 'Email has already been submitted'; // Change to your error message
$name = $tag['name'];
if ($name == $fieldName) {
    if (is_already_submitted($formName, $fieldName, $_POST[$name])) {
        $result->invalidate($tag, $errorMessage);
    }
}
return $result;
}

// use the next line if your field is a **required email** field on your     form
add_filter('wpcf7_validate_email*', 'my_validate_email', 10, 2);
// use the next line if your field is an **email** field not required on your form
add_filter('wpcf7_validate_email', 'my_validate_email', 10, 2);

// use the next line if your field is a **required text** field
 add_filter('wpcf7_validate_text*', 'my_validate_email', 10, 2);
// use the next line if your field is a **text** field field not required on your form 
add_filter('wpcf7_validate_text', 'my_validate_email', 10, 2);
```

please help me how to get previous 6 months mail and check

Comment: thank you for  edit code to readable format